# Run a SSIS Package Using Batch File

Tags: ssis, dtexec

need some help in executing my SSIS package from command prompt.
below is the path of my DTExec file and the package path. when i run this , i am getting an error "missing argument for option "file"

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe"/f

"C:\Users\myname\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SSIS tutorials\SSIS tutorials\filtering duplicates using fuzzy grouping.dtsx"
```

please help

Comment: Is the dtexec.exe invocation followed by the dtsx filename on the same line?

Comment: @Ramya have you tried the provided answer, if so i am waiting for a reply to give more help

Comment: Hot tip: don't ever use a space when naming things. (i.e. folders or SSIS packages). It might save you a lot of hassle

Answer (score 0):

When installed Integration Services the DTExec path *(`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\`)* is added by default to `PATH` environment variable so you can use the following command *(make sure it is one line command)*

```
Dtexec /f "C:\Users\myname\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SSIS tutorials\SSIS tutorials\filtering duplicates using fuzzy grouping.dtsx"
```

*Also check spacing between arguments*

**Reference**

- [dtexec Utility (SSIS Tool) TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue by placing everything on one line as criticalfix and Hadi mentioned above.  Make sure there are no returns after the /f argument, just a space.